# ASP.NET with Video and Voice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, voice

I have to receive voice from my user's microphone into my webpage and save it into database. I want to know, is ASP.NET supports Voice and Video ? if yes then which namespace or dll required. Any other information in this regard will be helpful. What is start point to use voice in asp.net webpage?

Comment: And more specifically before your question gets closed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668324/looking-for-the-net-video-processing-library

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630858/which-audio-library-to-use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776179/video-processing-in-net

Comment: @Mike Atlas, you saw a question here (in terms of how questions should be asked on SO)? Hmm, strange.

Comment: @Mike Atlas, none of those links apply to ASP.NET.  This question is very different when asked about a desktop vs web context.

Comment: If you wish to understand what happened, I'd suggest you ask about it on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft is generally pushing Silverlight for video/audio functionality.  You can build your whole application in Silverlight or build just a Silverlight widget to be used in a larger ASP.NET application.

**Video and Audio (Silverlight QuickStart)**

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/audioandvideo/

**Audio and Video Overview**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189078%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

**Your First Step to the Silverlight Voice/Video Chatting Client/Server**

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightVoiceVideoChat.aspx

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov: using voice feature in webpage.

Comment: @Thomas, I added some links, but you really should learn how to do research on basic concepts and utilize Q&A for specific details you need help on or need clarified.

Comment: @Thomas, could you please describe what do you mean by *voice feature in a webpage*?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: receiving voice from user's microphone in our webpage.

Comment: @Samuel Neff: your last link is awesome.